# Shell scripting issue - remove lines from a file

Tags: shell

I am completely new to shell scripting and I have a "little" problem with something I have to do.

I have a file containing lines like this :

```
LineNumber;Log
2;Ligne ignorÈ¨e : Collaborateur PABC842 inactif et non prÈ¨sent dans Machine
2;La valeur (CDD) dans la colonne [Type_contrat] n'est pas dans le liste (FON|CDP|CDI|CDII). Le rÈ¿gle CA1 a ignorÈ¨ ou a dÈ¨sactivÈ¨ la ligne pour le collaborateur PABC842
```

I have to remove lines from this file where I have the values :

```
"inactif et non prÈ¨sent dans Machine"
```

and :

```
"Le rÈ¿gle CA1 a ignorÈ¨ ou a dÈ¨sactivÈ¨ la ligne"
```

The first line of the file must be ignored and the result of the file without the lines above must be redirected in another file...

I just don't know ho to do it. May be because of the special characters.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could u please post the coding parts in English..

Comment: @PraveenVinny: could you please spell the English word *"you"* correctly, and notice that the OP's use of French is completely irrelevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use grep with the -v option

```
% grep -v "Le rÈ¿gle CA1 a ignorÈ¨ ou a dÈ¨sactivÈ¨ la ligne\|inactif et non prÈ¨sent dans Machine" test.txt

LineNumber;Log
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that awk provides the most convenient solution. Try this :

```
awk '(NR!=1) && ($0!="line1") && ($0!="line2") { print }' file > outputFile
```

where *line1* and *line2* are the lines you want to skip. Replace them with the actual values. 
The (NR!=1) condition blocks the first line.

EDIT : The above code suppress 1st line and lines matching line1 & line2. If you want to ignore the 1st line from comparison(ie- print it even it matches line1 or line2), you have to do:

```
 awk '{if(NR==1) print; else if ($0!="line1" && $0!="line2")  print }' file > output
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a good tool for a job like this:

```
sed '1d;/inactif et non prÈ¨sent dans Machine/d;/Le rÈ¿gle CA1 a ignorÈ¨ ou a dÈ¨sactivÈ¨ la ligne/d;' file > otherfile
```